# why the destructor is not called in this program?

Tags: c++

I have made a function that instantiate the class, and do some operations. After that the function is returned, this means the scope is over. Once the scope is over,it should have called the destructor of the class. However, I don't see that the destructor is called. What is the reason behind it? Am I missing something here?

```
/***

The static member in the class is just a declaration, whose namespace scope is limited to the class.
One need to define it in the corresponding source of the class header. This way, the static member is
allocated a space on the Data segment. In case the static member is not defined, then the linker will
throw an error.

**/

class category_to_subcategory
{
     /** static members have just declaration not definition **/
     static QMultiMap<QString,QString>m_cat_to_subcat;

 public:
     /** The const can give a definition to it within the class, thus no need to define it **/
     /** C++ allows only "integer const static" types to be defined within a class */
     /** both are same const static or static const **/
     const static  int categ_const = 10;
     static void insert_subcat();
     /** template **/
     QList<QString> get_subcat(QString &cat);
     QList<QString> get_subcat(const QString &cat);
     ~category_to_subcategory();
};

/** When you want to map a string to string, you can use QMultimap **/
/** It is quite easy to get the values using QMultimap **/
/** definition of m_cat_to_subcat, the namescope is bind to the class name - category_to_subcategory  **/
QMultiMap<QString,QString> category_to_subcategory::m_cat_to_subcat;

 void category_to_subcategory::insert_subcat()
 {
     qDebug()<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
     m_cat_to_subcat.clear();
     m_cat_to_subcat.insert("OS", "Linux");
     m_cat_to_subcat.insert("OS", "Windows");
     m_cat_to_subcat.insert("OS", "MAC");
     m_cat_to_subcat.insert("SHELL", "BASH");
     m_cat_to_subcat.insert("SHELL", "KSH");
     m_cat_to_subcat.insert("SHELL", "CSH");
     m_cat_to_subcat.insert("MOUSE", "WIRED");
     m_cat_to_subcat.insert("MOUSE", "WIRELESS");

 }

 QList<QString> category_to_subcategory::get_subcat(QString &cat)
 {
     qDebug()<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
     if(category_to_subcategory::m_cat_to_subcat.empty()) {
          category_to_subcategory::insert_subcat();
      }
      QList<QString> subcat_list = m_cat_to_subcat.values(cat);
      return subcat_list;
 }

 QList<QString> category_to_subcategory::get_subcat(const QString &cat)
 {
     qDebug()<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
     if(category_to_subcategory::m_cat_to_subcat.empty()) {
          category_to_subcategory::insert_subcat();
     }
     QList<QString> subcat_list = m_cat_to_subcat.values(cat);
     return subcat_list;
 }

category_to_subcategory::~category_to_subcategory()
{
   qDebug()<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
   delete this;
}

void function_to_QMAP()
{
    qDebug()<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    category_to_subcategory *cat_to_subcat_Instance = new category_to_subcategory;
    QString cat = "OS";
    qDebug()<<cat_to_subcat_Instance->get_subcat(cat);
    cat = "SHELL";
    qDebug()<<cat_to_subcat_Instance->get_subcat(cat);
    cat = "MOUSE";
    qDebug()<<cat_to_subcat_Instance->get_subcat(cat);
    /** Passing just the string will throw an error **/
    //qDebug()<<cat_to_subcat_Instance->get_subcat("MOUSE");
    /** no matching function for call to 'category_to_subcategory::get_subcat(const char[6]); */

    qDebug()<<"The const category is"<<cat_to_subcat_Instance->get_subcat("OS");
    qDebug()<<"The static const integer defined in class value is "<<category_to_subcategory::categ_const;
}

void function_op_finish()
{
    qDebug()<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    function_to_QMAP();
    function_op_finish();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: why are you pasting X pages of code and not telling us which exactly function you are talking about?

Comment: Putting `delete this` in a destructor is never, ever the right thing to do. `delete` invokes the destructor, not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are confusing the two types of memory allocation in C++ - stack based (local variables are allocated on the stack and automatically destructed when the function exits) and heap based (allocated using 'new' and the programmer takes responsibility for making sure 'delete' is called at some point)

Here is a [friendly tutorial](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html) on the differences, and welcome to the joys and sorrows of manually managing memory in C++ (it's probably the biggest source of errors and problems in the language). Note the link refers specifically to C instead of C++, but the concepts are the same in both.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't `delete` `cat_to_subcat_Instance`. It's a memory leak: the object is created, but never destroyed.

In your particular code fragment, I see zero need for allocating `cat_to_subcat_Instance` dynamically. Why not do it the easy way?

```
void function_to_QMAP()
{
    qDebug()<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    category_to_subcategory cat_to_subcat_Instance;
    QString cat = "OS";
    qDebug()<<cat_to_subcat_Instance.get_subcat(cat);
    cat = "SHELL";
    qDebug()<<cat_to_subcat_Instance.get_subcat(cat);
    cat = "MOUSE";
    qDebug()<<cat_to_subcat_Instance.get_subcat(cat);
    /** Passing just the string will throw an error **/
    //qDebug()<<cat_to_subcat_Instance.get_subcat("MOUSE");
    /** no matching function for call to 'category_to_subcategory::get_subcat(const char[6]); */

    qDebug()<<"The const category is"<<cat_to_subcat_Instance.get_subcat("OS");

    qDebug()<<"The static const integer defined in class value is "<<category_to_subcategory::categ_const;


}
```

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI: because that's not how _dynamic_ allocation work. But that's how stack allocation works. See my edited answer for an example of how to allocate on the stack.

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI: Becase the variable is a pointer-to-object. The variable is destroyed when it gets out of scope. So, the **pointer** is destroyed when it gets out of scope. The object pointed by it is not destroyed. If you want to use a 'pointer-like thing' that will automatically destroy the object too - use smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You allocated an object of type category_to_subcategory in the heap using operator `new`.

```
category_to_subcategory *cat_to_subcat_Instance = new category_to_subcategory;
```

That to delete this object you need explicitly call operator `delete`.

Also take into account that the destructor of class category_to_subcategory is invalid.

```
category_to_subcategory::~category_to_subcategory()
{
   qDebug()<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
   delete this;
}
```

Its calling will result in recursive call of the destructor until the stack memory will be exhausted.
Remove the statement with delete.

```
category_to_subcategory::~category_to_subcategory()
{
   qDebug()<<__PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
}
```